# Recursion function in Haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion

I wanted to count the first 27 even numbers using recursion in Haskell. Below is my attempted code but I need it to count the first 27 even numbers in the list:

```
countEven []= 0

countEven (x:xs) = if even x then (countEven xs) + 1 else countEven xs
```

Comment: Do you really have to use recursion? `countEven = sum . take 27 . filter even` will do the trick.

Comment: I already know that but i need it with recursion. Can anyone help!

Comment: @ChrisMartin You probably meant `countEven = length . take 27 . filter even`. `sum` gets the sum of all the integers in the list. It doesn't "count" the number of elements in the list.

Comment: Whoops, misread the question. Wait, what does it mean to count the first 27 even numbers, then? Isn't the answer always `27`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be the following is what you want:

```
countEven xs = countEvenStart xs 27
    where
        countEvenStart []     _ = []
        countEvenStart _      0 = []
        countEvenStart (x:xs) n = if (even x) then x : countEvenStart xs (n-1)
                                  else countEvenStart xs n
```

You can use it as `countEven [1..]`.
If you need the sum of them, just apply `sum` to the result.